# Why is that sometimes eigenvalue decomposition produces a rotational matrix, other times it does not

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations, paradoxes

Suppose we want to perform eigenvalue decomposition on this matrix:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1.5 && -0.5\\ -0.5  && 1.5 \end{bmatrix}$$

I obtain the corresponding eigenvectors as $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 2$, and eigen-vector $v_1 = [1, 1]^T$, $v_2 = [1, -1]^T$.

So our $Q$ as in $P = Q\Lambda Q^T$ is given by

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1\\ 1  && -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Which is not a rotational matrix after we normalize it!

But we can alternatively pick our eigenvectors as 
 $v_1 = [1, 1]^T$, $v_2 = [-1, 1]^T$. Notice $v_2$ has changed by a sign

Then obviously 
 $$Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1\\ 1  && 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Is a rotational matrix after normalization. In fact, it is trivial to see it rotates by $45^\circ$

Can someone resolve this paradox?

Comment: What's the paradox? The two matrices are still both orthogonal (the former is a combination of a rotation and a reflection), and the span of their columns separately are the same lines. So they are both valid eigenvector matrices. Since you have symmetry, you should expect the orthogonality, but in general you should not expect to have a rotation. For indeed, as you've pointed out, if you have an eigenvector matrix which is a rotation matrix, you can always flip a sign in one column, obtaining a new eigenvector matrix with determinant $-1$, which can never be a rotation.

Comment: @Ian But I thought the intuition for eigenvalue decomposition is that you rotate, scale by the eigenvalues, and then rotate. But you are saying that these eigenmatrices are not rotations in general. How do you explain this disparity?

Comment: not only they are rotations but expansions

Comment: 1. That intuition is not correct in the nonsymmetric case, even in the nonsymmetric but diagonalizable case. But it is essentially correct in the symmetric case. 2. In the symmetric case, I think you can always choose the eigenvector matrix to be a rotation matrix. But it is also valid for it to contain reflections as well. But the same basic thing applies, you rotate and/or reflect, rescale, and then rotate and/or reflect back.